# Expression resolves to an unused function Only instance methods can be declared @IBAction

Tags: swift

I'm following a youtube series and I've done exactly as the guy in the film but still i get errors please help. (:

if you know the answer please help.

```
@IBAction func resetClicked(sender:UIButton) {

            func reset() {

            }
            plays = [:]
            img1.image = nil
            img2.image = nil
            img3.image = nil
            img4.image = nil
            img5.image = nil
            img6.image = nil
            img7.image = nil
            img8.image = nil
            img9.image = nil
        }


    }

    func checkForWin() {
        var whoWon = ["I":0,"you":1]
        for (key,value) in whoWon {
            if((plays[7] == value && plays[8] == value && plays[9] == value))
             (plays[4] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[6] == value)
             (plays[1] == value && plays[2] == value && plays[3] == value)
             (plays[1] == value && plays[4] == value && plays[7] == value)
             (plays[2] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[8] == value)
             (plays[1] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[9] == value)
            (plays[3] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[7] == value)) {

                self.userMessage.hidden = false
                self.userMessage.text = "Looks like \(key) won"
                self.reset.hidden = false
                self.done = true
            }






        }

    }

    func aiDeciding2() {

    }
    func aiTurn() {


    }
```

Comment: what and *where* is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: plus it is a type that you added an extra `}` before `checkForWin` function ?

Comment: You also have an extra `)` at the first line of your `if` statement in the `checkForWin ` function

Comment: Is your `func resetClicked` inside of your view controller? The error message suggests that it is not...

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a function inside of an IBAction. Your error is the

```
func reset() {
}
```

Also make sure your IBAction is inside your view controller code